# Force BarLegend to show numbers

Tags: legending

I have the following BarLegend:

```
BarLegend[{"GreenPinkTones", {-0.99, 0.99}}]
```

It does not show -0.99 and 0.99. How can I force it to show these numbers at the beginning and end respectively?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
BarLegend[{"GreenPinkTones", {-0.99, 0.99}}, 
 "Ticks" -> Join[Range[-.75, .75, .25], {-.99, .99}]]
```

[image]

Comment: The "Ticks" label is Red Highlighted in version 12.3 but it works. Adding labels ("12Ax230V (2760VA)") is also Red.
BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 8280}}, 
 "Ticks" -> {{230 12, "12Ax230V (2760VA)"}, {230 16, 
    "16Ax230V (3680VA)"}, {230 24, "24Ax230V (5520VA)"}, {230 12 3, 
    "3x12Ax230V (8280VA)"}}]