# BarLegend tick labels

Tags: legending, ticks

I am doing a ListContourPlot of my data, but to achieve a solid plot I needed to first take a logarithm of the "height". Now I'd like to force the ticks on my BarLegend to certain values, but I have no idea how to do that. [image: My example]

To rephrase... I have a plot (seen on the picture), but I'd like to change the labels on the BarLegend, but I need them to remain where they are. To put it simply, I need to replace each TickLabel value with its exponential.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215745/force-barlegend-to-show-numbers

Comment: This lets me change the Ticks to specific ones, but not to make them evenly distributed even tho the values are scaled logarithmically

Comment: I am just guessing if you want something similar to this. you can always change the legend label. It's always best to post a minimal example the problem can be recreated. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76168/how-to-add-own-description-to-barlegend

Answer (score 8):

```
 data = Table[3 Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.05}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.05}]; 

 ListContourPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Contours -> {Automatic, 30}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, None, 
    LegendLabel -> "Spectral Density"], Below]]
```

[image]

Add the option `LabelingFunction -> (Exp[HoldForm @ #3] &)` to `BarLegend`:

```
ListContourPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Contours -> {Automatic, 30}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, None, 
     LabelingFunction -> (Exp[HoldForm @ #3] &), 
     LegendLabel -> "Spectral Density"], Below]]
```

[image]

**Note:** To see the arguments of the pure function used to set `LabelingFunction`, inspect:

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-5, 5}}, None, LabelingFunction -> FOO]
```

[image]